# Image manipulation in Node JS

Tags: node.js, image-manipulation

I am new to node js and I want to convert a png image to pure black and white (not grayscale) image using native node js libraries. All I know that bit depth of black and white image should be 1. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options, both with the same package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm

Docs : http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html

**Option 1**

Convert the image in to monochrome

```
gm("img.png").monochrome()
```

**Option 2**

Use black and white thresholds to manually specify the ranges to be converted to pure black and white

```
//pixels below `threshold` become black.
gm("img.png").blackThreshold(red ,green , blue , opacity)

//pixels above the threshold become white
gm("img.png").whiteThreshold(red, green, blue, opacity)
```

*Docs*

http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#blackThreshold
http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#whiteThreshold

Personally I think Option 2 suits your needs best.

Comment: What about converting an image to pure grey. Is it possible?

Comment: You cold try using gm("img.png").type("Grayscale")